# How to convert string into map having value as a comma separated list?

Tags: java, string, groovy

I have a string in the format - "[21:[1,2,3],22:[1,2,3]]". How am I supposed to convert this into a key-value map having list as a value?

Comment: what is the expected output? can you give us an example?

Comment: Are you asking about Java or Groovy?

Comment: Either you find a standardized format which looks like this (which i am not aware of) or you start parsing that string yourself.

Comment: groovy is a superset of java. so i can use any solution

Comment: If you can use any solution, where is your attempt and where did you fail?

Comment: This looks like the `.toString()` on a map of Groovy.  So your life will become alot easier, if you fix the place, that hands you down this string (e.g. dont turn it into a string at all or use a format that is made for this like JSON)

Answer (score 1):

Some straight forward groovy:

```
String s = "[21:[1,2,3],22:[1,2,3],23:[6:[1,2],7:[3,4]]]"
Map res = Eval.me s

assert [1,2,3] == res[22]
assert [3,4] == res[23][7]
```

Comment: Thanks mate. Great answer. Solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

1.Remove the [ and ] at the beginning and end. 21:[1,2,3],22:[1,2,3]

2.Do a string split for ],

3. For each element, String split again for :[.

   First element is your Map key
    Second element (comma separated) can be converted to list using array conversion

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove square bracket(**[**)  `removeAll("\\[","")`
2. Remove last square bracket(**]**,") together with trailing comma(**,**) and replace with full-colon(**:**) `removeAll("\\[",":")`
3. Replace double square brackets at the end of String `removeAll("\\]]","")`
4. Split the remaining String using `split(":")`
5. Then loop

   ```
   String x =  "[21:[1,2,3],22:[1,2,3]]";

   final HashMap<String,List<String>> test = new HashMap<>();

   final String s = x.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\],", ":").
           replaceAll("\\]]", "");

    final String[] split = s.split(":");

   for(int i =0;i<split.length;i++)
       test.put(split[i],Arrays.asList(split[++i]));

   test.forEach((k,v)-> System.out.println(k +" " +v))
   ```

*Result*
[image]